# Quaid js require only numbers

Tags: javascript, validation

In Quiad js how do i make sure it accepts nothing but numbers, i have tried pattern="/d*"

but to no avail.

```
   <p><label for="mobile">Mobile Phone <small class="hint">
   (if you have one)</small>  </label> 
    <input type="tel" name="mobile" id="mobile" size="13" maxlength="13" 
   class="mobile" pattern="/d*" required>
```

Comment: I don't know what *Quiad js* is but try this pattern `pattern="\d*"`.

Comment: its a validation library for js

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to use html5 form inputs pattern, change to `pattern="\d*"`, like:

```
<p><label for="mobile">Mobile Phone <small class="hint">
   (if you have one)</small>  </label> 
    <input type="tel" name="mobile" id="mobile" size="13" maxlength="13" 
    class="mobile" pattern="\d*" required />
    </p>
```

Added

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" pattern="\d*" size="40" maxlength="100" required />
```

See: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rjwzp/)

Comment: how would i do that for text, for example not allow a user to enter numbers in a text field.

Comment: <p><label for="username">Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="40" maxlength="100" required/>

Comment: @NorthernLove you could use pattern="\d*" for input type text as well, check by editing the jsfiddle demo